# Do I have to reinstall CUDA 9.0 to use tfjs-node-gpu?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to run `@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu` example on my laptop (Dell xps 15/GTX 1050), with ubuntu18.04 and nvidia-390 installed.

When I try to run an app, I end up encountering this error message, complaining about the versions of CUDA.

```
Error: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Previously I have installed CUDA toolkit with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

and the installed CUDA version is 9.1, instead of 9.0.

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

So now I have version mismatch problem! Is there any way that I run apps with CUDA 9.1, instead of reinstalling it?

My naive approach would be to creating a symbolic link... but is this a reliable solution?

Or can I make `@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu` to rely on CUDA 9.1 not 9.0?

Thanks!

Comment: You muist have CUDA 9.0 installed

Comment: Well I am now in a new tough situation. CUDA 9.0 requires GCC other than 7.3.0, which is default in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue - you need CUDA 9.0 installed: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15604

The underlying binary for TensorFlow.js on Node.js is prebuilt and has to be linked against a specific version of CUDA. Please follow this issue on support to enable building a custom libtensorflow optimized for your system and library settings: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/571